# Open and edit excel via python

Tags: python, excel

I want to import an existing excel file and edit it. But when i copy the excel file and try to edit on it i get some errors. I did not get errors while trying to execute "write" command. But when i am trying to read some values in the cell, i am having problem.

```
import xlsxwriter
from xlrd import open_workbook
from xlwt import Workbook, easyxf
import xlwt
from xlutils.copy import copy


workbook=open_workbook("month.xlsx")
sheet=workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
print sheet.nrows
book = copy(workbook)

w_sheet=book.get_sheet(0)
print w_sheet.cell(0,0).value

Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "excel.py", line 18, in <module>
print w_sheet.cell(0,0).value
AttributeError: 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'cell'
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used this library, but looking at the documentation I think you are trying to do something it doesn't support.  [The worksheet documentation](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html) lists it's functionality and cell() is not there.

I think this library is for writing excel only, not reading.

Perhaps try [pandas read_excel()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) to read the excel documents you create?

You can the use [pandas iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) on the resulting dataframe to get the value you want:

```
value=pd.read_excel("file.xlsx", sheet_name="sheet").iloc[0,0]
```

I think that's correct, although I can't run the code to check just now...